# Ubuntu 20.04, unable to get Xbox One controller working wirelessly

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth

Running on an AMD 64-bit (Ryzen 7) X570 MB. No matter which route from the snap store, or terminal I cannot get the Xbox ONE controller to work with the USB Wireless dongle or sync up via Bluetooth. It works on Steam fine only when it is wire connected. I have an Xbox 360 controller that works fine, wirelessly, with no additional work to be performed.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I really want to stay on a Linux OS and not have to revert to Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You have do deactivate the Enhanced Retransmission Mode (ERTM) to have a proper bluetooth connection (as sudo):

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
```

To make this change permanent, the package `sysfsutils` is required

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

Then add to `/etc/sysfs.conf` the folllowing:

```
module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm = 1
```

Now restart the service

```
sudo service sysfsutils restart
```

The controller should now connect properly.